# Optimize if else condition with (repeatable actions in branches)

Tags: if-statement, optimization

I have this code. At first jobDone is false and the program does the first step, then the second and sets the jobDone variable to true stating that all tasks completed successfully.

But I might choose to run this bit of code again and I don't want to do the first step again since it might not be necessary. So if the job has been done at least once and if checkSomething() concludes that everything is OK it should go ahead and do only secondStep();

Otherwise, if checkSomething() finds out that something is wrong then I must repeat the first and as well the second step (like in the initial situation).

```
jobDone = false;
if (jobDone) {
    if (checkSomething()) {
         doSecondStep();
    } else {
         doFirstStep();
         doSecondStep();
    }
} else {
    doFirstStep();
    doSecondStep();
    jobDone = true;
}
```

But I feel that i'm repeating myself. Is there a better way of writing this? Thank yoou.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(jobDone && checkSomething()) {
    doSecondStep();
} else {
    doFirstStep();
    doSecondStep();
    jobDone = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second step is always executed, I suggest you move that to the end first:

```
jobDone = false;
if (jobDone) {
    if (!checkSomething()) {
         doFirstStep();
    }
} else {
    doFirstStep();
    jobDone = true;
}
doSecondStep();
```

However, there's only one condition that would cause doFirstStep() not to be executed and that's when jobDone == true and checkSomething == false, so we could just check for that.

The whole thing can be summarized to three lines:

```
if (!(jobDone && !checkSomething())) { doFirstStep(); }
jobDone = !jobDone;
doSecondStep();
```